# Can we have a div having aria-role = navigation inside a div having aria-role = navigation

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

Is this a valid scenario:

Code:

```
<html>
   <div role = "navigation">
      <div role = "navigation" aria-label = "Navigate between these 2 links">
      </div>
      <div role = "region" aria-label = "Filters">
      </div>
   </div>
</html>
```

Having a role navigation inside a div having role navigation. Is it a valid scenario and is it valid under design pattern followed? Is it a good practice or should i replace inner role as region

Comment: why would you need that? looking at the role attribute, it is primarily used for accessibility and device adaption so I don't see the need in repeating the role inside a role

Answer (score 2):

Can you do that?  Yes, it's not invalid html.  The navigation role and the `<nav>` element have a [content model](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element) that allows nested roles as long as the nested role is not `main`.

Keep in mind that the navigation role and `<nav>` element are landmark roles so they will allow a screen reader user to jump to that section.  Having too many landmarks on your page starts to diminish the usefulness of landmarks.

Given the limited info on your scenario, it's difficult to say whether you should be doing this.